# Wi-fi not working on Android at home

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

My wifi is not working on my Android 4.4 tablet, but the tablet says it is  connected (although the icon is red rather than the usual white) and the router says the tablet is connected. The tablet gets an IP of `192.168.1.5`

```
1|root@rk3026:/ # ip a                                                         
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: ip6tnl0: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:a2:13:33:de:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::aea2:13ff:fe33:de96/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: p2p0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DORMANT qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:a2:13:33:de:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@rk3026:/ # ip r                                                           
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  metric 304 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  scope link 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.5  metric 304 
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  scope link
```

The router has IP `192.168.1.1`. For some reason the router identifies two connected devices with IP `192.168.1.5` and `192.168.1.2`, but changing the IP of the tablet manually to `192.168.1.2` does not help.

For comparison my laptop works in the network through wired ethernet

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:26:0a:15:4a:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.4/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute em1
       valid_lft 594523sec preferred_lft 594523sec
    inet6 fe80::c497:8044:af6c:4a3d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:13:0b:8f:90:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
$ ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev em1 proto dhcp metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev em1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.4 metric 100
```

The table can ping itself at `192.168.1.`5, and the laptop can ping itself at `192.168.1.4` and the router at `192.168.1.1`; but the tablet cannot ping anything else, and the laptop cannot ping the tablet. When I turn everything off and on several times, it sometimes work.